# How should ISerializable object store binary data?

Tags: .net, serializable

I have a reference type which contains raw image data in unmanaged memory.  It's clear how to store the metadata (width, height) using `SerializationInfo`, but what is the best way to store a BLOB?

The only thing I can see is using `Convert.ToBase64String` which requires a whole bunch of copying.  Is there a more straightforward way?

Answer (score 2):

Update: There is a much better way of handling this!

What you need to do is look at the [`StreamingContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.serialization.streamingcontext.state.aspx) passed in to `GetObjectData`, the [`StreamingContext.State`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.serialization.streamingcontext.state.aspx) property can tell you what kind of serialization is happening. If you get passed the state `Clone` or `CrossAppDomain` you may be able to reuse the existing handles you have to the unmanaged blob and just pass the handle pointers in to the `SerializationInfo` object.

---

You will need to do a bunch of copying no matter what you choose, but `Convert.ToBase64String` is unnecessary, you can just serialize the managed `byte[]` you would have passed in to `Convert.ToBase64String` and that should be fine.

---

I do not know if there is any special case efficency's for `byte[]`, however all Seralizations [get turned in to a byte stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233843.aspx) during the transfer process. So by encoding in Base64 you are going to be doing

1. Read your unmanaged blob and convert it to a managed `byte[]`
2. Convert your `byte[]` in to a `string` via `ToBase64String` (increasing the size by a factor of <sup>4</sup>/<sub>3</sub> due to the encoding)
3. Pass the encoded string with a tag name in to the `SerializationInfo`
4. Pass the rest of the metadata in to the `SerializationInfo` with their respetive tags
5. The serializer takes all of the tag+object combos and turns them in to a byte stream to be passed on to the destination
6. The deserializer takes the byte stream and turns it back in to a collection of tags and objects
7. You get your `string` back using the same tag name
8. You get your metadata back using the tags you saved them under.
9. Convert the `string` back in to a `byte[]` via `FromBase64String`
10. Convert the `byte[]` back in to the unmanaged binary blob.

If you never encode to a string and just pass the `byte[]` in as the object to the `SerializationInfo` object the steps are pretty much the same, it just does not have that <sup>4</sup>/<sub>3</sub> size increase of the datablob to encode the binary data as text.

1. Read your unmanaged blob and convert it to a managed `byte[]`
2. Pass the `byte[]` with a tag name in to the `SerializationInfo`
3. Pass the rest of the metadata in to the `SerializationInfo` with their respetive tags
4. The serializer takes all of the tag+object combos and turns them in to a byte stream to be passed on to the destination
5. The deserializer takes the byte stream and turns it back in to a collection of tags and objects
6. You get your `byte[]` back using the same tag name
7. You get your metadata back using the tags you saved them under.
8. Convert the `byte[]` back in to the unmanaged binary blob.

So I guess the "optimization" is transmitting as a `byte[]` has the benefit of not increasing the amount of data you have to transmit to the desearizer.

Comment: That's unfortunate.  Is `byte[]` special-cased for efficiency, do you know, or is it going to store the metadata followed by each individual element as a separate item?  Is there any other easy way to just stash a few objects between runs of the program?

Comment: I added a extensive update to answer the first part of your question. For your 2nd question it depends on what your goal is: simplest implementation, minimum size, human readable, cross platform support, cross .NET framework version support? (if the answer to the last one is "no" then [`BinaryFormmater`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) may be the "easiest" solution)?

Comment: @BenVoigt I was not thinking earlier, Yes any kind of object that is passed in to [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/skf8dbad.aspx) of `AddValue(` ***could*** have optimizations. What will happen is it will call `GetObjectData()` on the object that is passed in and the nested searlizer does whatever optimizations it chooses to do (So it is up to the seralizer for `Array` to determine if there is any optimizations or not)

Comment: One thing you should also consid,er If you serialize to a `byte[]` and you then pass your searialization stream on to a `XMLSearalizer` it will encode the `byte[]` files as hexidecimal, which would be much more inefficient in size than the Base64 encoding, so maybe Base64 could be better.

Comment: That's what I suspected.  Although I was worried it might be even worse, e.g. comma-separated list of decimal-encoded values.